# Suggest me a music-player with "Global Hot keys" and "mono-stereo sound output toggle" features 

Tags: windows, media-player, speakers, hotkeys

I am searching for a player which has mono-speaker-sound output feature as well as Global hot keys ..

I tried using wmplayer .. which has global Hot keys support but I can't set mono-speaker output ..
and on the other hand I used VLC player which has mono-speaker o/p but doesn't support Global Hot keys ..

The reason I need mono-speaker o/p is : I have only one speaker working .. (my right speaker is out of work)
And I guess you know the benefits of Global Hot Keys ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foobar2000 supports [global hotkeys](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Preferences:General:Keyboard_Shortcuts) and has just about every audio effect you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

[Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) has both as well

Else I recommend you look into this article on using [AutoHotKey with Winamp](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Winamp.htm), which might even work with other players